# How can I present the following Symfony form data to generate fixed text fields?

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, symfony

I have the below Controller and FormTypes which loops over generating the form as in the this screenshot for each <kbd>Member</kbd>. My problem is that I just want the Member names to be fixed text and not in a select box. However, the only way I know to iterate over this for ever `$member` is by the `EntityType`. Am I going about this the wrong way?:

[image]

**Controller:**

```
public function batchInvoicesAction(Request $request)
     {
        $members = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->findActiveMembers();
        $batch = new InvoiceBatch();
        foreach ($members as $member) {
                    $invoice=new Invoice();
                    $invoice->setMemberId($member);
                    batch->addInvoiceId($invoice);
        }
        $form=$this->createForm(InvoiceBatchType::class, $batch);
        /* ... */
    }
```

**InvoiceBatchType:**

```
/* ... */
->add('invoice_ids', CollectionType::class, array(
     'entry_type' => InvoiceType::class,
))
/* ... */
```

**InvoiceType:**

```
/* ... */
->add('member_id', EntityType::class, array(
          'class' => 'AppBundle:Member',
          'choice_label' => 'FullName',
          'label'=>'Member',
))
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data)

You should remove `member_id` from the form builder.
Then, using event, add new [unmapped](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) and `read-only` text field with default value of the corresponding member.

If you need simple `text` (no inputs) you will need to play a little with decorators/labels.

Comment: Hi @po_taka, thank you - ideally it'd just by `text` with no inputs. My thought is that there's no need to send over all member objects in an `EntityType` just so that I can loop through every iteration for every row - especially if I don't need to be generating all these redundant `<option></option>`s  for every select box on the page (there could be a couple of hundred rows in the 'real world' page - that'd be 10,000+ `<option></option>`s instead of just the 100+ I need...!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. What you do in listener is your business logic. You could fetch 1 row, you can fetch 1kk rows.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding listeners then as I'm still new to all this. My thought is that for each invoice row, the Member entity is being looped over and generating `<option>{{ member.firstname}}</option>` for every single member...and repeating this for every single invoice line. Whereas all I actually need is an `<input value="{{ member.firstname }}"></input>` for each invoice line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, events will do the work. See this examples: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html Specially the last one. They are adding/deleting form element, based on some saved data. Simple pseudo code for your event: `$invoice = $event->getData(); $event->getForm()->add('member', 'text', ['data' => $invoice->getMember()->getName()];` Since I don't know your business model I can't help any further.